# Jython: pythonic equivalent to java.util.concurrent.Callable?

Tags: java, python, jython, future, callable

I'm using a simple pythonic queue in conjunction with a pythonic Thread subclass...

```
class WorkerThread( threading.Thread ):
  def __init__( self, *args, **kvargs ):
    threading.Thread.__init__( self, *args, **kvargs )
    self.input_queue = Queue()

  def send( self, item ):
    assert type( item ) is list
    assert item # i.e. must have at least one element
    # check that first item is callable
    assert hasattr( item[ 0 ], "__call__" )
    self.input_queue.put( item )

  def close( self ):
    self.input_queue.put( None )
    self.input_queue.join()

  def run( self ):
    while True:
      method_call_elements = self.input_queue.get()
      if method_call_elements is None: # "poison pill"
        break
      method_args = method_call_elements[ 1 : ]
      method_call_elements[ 0 ]( *method_args ) 
      self.input_queue.task_done()
    self.input_queue.task_done()
    return
```

... so what you submit is a list, the first item of which is a method, and the optional other elements of 
which are any parameters you might want to supply to the method.  NB can't do this sort of fun stuff in Java!

The question is: is there a simple pythonic method of returning a value from the called method?  In Java obviously you have the Callable and Future interfaces to play with.  And using more such Java classes I can see how the code could be changed... indeed there are several possibilities I suppose.  But I just wondered whether Python has any provision for dealing with "Future"-type situations?

BTW I had a look at the Definitive Guide, http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/Concurrency.html - but this didn't seem to give any non-Java solution

***later:***

anyone interested, this is my Java-oriented solution:

```
@property
def size( lmm_self ):
  class FindNodeMapSizeTask( Callable ):
    def call( self ):
      genLog.info( "thread %s - inside FindNodeMapSizeTask.call()", Thread.currentThread().id )
      return len( lmm_self.id_to_node_map )
  size_result = FutureTask( FindNodeMapSizeTask() )
  lmm_self.internal_ops_worker_thread.send([ size_result.run ])
  genLog.info( "thread %s - waiting for Future.get()...", Thread.currentThread().id )
  map_size = size_result.get()
  genLog.info( "thread %s - ... got Future.get(): %s", Thread.currentThread().id, map_size)
  return map_size
```

typical output:

thread 20 - waiting for Future.get()...

thread 21 - inside FindNodeMapSizeTask.call()

thread 20 - ... got Future.get(): 1121

tree size: 1121

size_result.get() blocks the return from size( lmm_self ) until the len( ... ) delivers its result even if a sleep( 1 ) is placed after method_call_elements = self.input_queue.get() in def send().

works OK but of course uses the Java FutureTask.  Any pythonic solution to this would be of interest to me...

***later still***

hmm... consulting my Beasley Python Essential Reference, I can see pretty clear way of doing sthg along these lines using threading.Event...

Comment: what do you mean exactly?  why don't you just store the return value for the function and return it from your run method? just define some variable `output = []` outside your while loop and then just `output.append(method_call_elements[0](*method_args))` and just return output.  You could also pass in an object instance to the method and let the method handle sending arguments back. I realize this might be different in Jython/working with threads.

Comment: A `Future` is called in Python a generator (which can be created in various ways). Reading through the code I agree with @JeffTratner though...

Comment: @JeffTratner thanks... but the problem in that case is identifying which result belongs to which submitted thing.  Obviously the thing that wants to receive the result could be passed along with the method and params... but how to hold up the calling thread until the result is delivered (Future.get())?

Comment: @JonClements excellent, thanks very much, this is very helpful.  I'm not sure how it would work in practice but I think you've provided a very valuable clue to give me a few ideas.

Comment: @JonClements specifically, if I may, is it possible to call .next() on a generator in Thread A and to get the same generator object to wait somehow for delivery of the result in Thread B???

Comment: I'm not a multi-threading/multi-process/greenlets expert. However, I think the answer is 'no'. You'll need to work "bottom to top", so that Thread 'b' causes a next(generator). You can share the generator using various tools in the Threading module - but this is out of my league at the moment, sorry to say.

Comment: @JonClements OK not to worry, thanks anyway

Comment: Wow, 8 years ago. Do you still need the answer? Hahaha